# With new XCode getting "Comparison of constant with boolean expression is always false"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

After downloading XCode 6.3, now all of a sudden for this following block of code:

```
AVKeyValueStatus tracksStatus = [inputAsset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&error];
if (!tracksStatus == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded)
{
      return;
}
```

I am now getting:

> Comparison of constant with boolean expression is always false
>   stackoverflow

Can anyone explain why is this happening all of a sudden and what would be the proper way to rewrite this expression?

Comment: Use `(not equal)` instead of `not (equal)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think instead of this:

```
if (!tracksStatus == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded)
```

you want this:

```
if (tracksStatus != AVKeyValueStatusLoaded)
```

(Assuming you want to compare if the two things are not equal.)

Answer (score 1):

I think this due to the operator predencence in C where ! is having higher precedence  than ==. See [enter link description here](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm). So try putting a () over "tracksStatus == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded"

```
if (!(tracksStatus == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded))
{
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this did work and what you say makes sense. I just went with the above answer just because it's a little more easy to make sense of when I read it.

Comment: It's Okay. no issues. In C it is also import to understand why you are getting a compiler warning like "Comparison of constant with boolean expression is always false ".

Answer (score 0):

By replacing this:

> if (!tracksStatus == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded)

with this:

> if (tracksStatus != AVKeyValueStatusLoaded)

WORKED!